# Overriding Resources from Generic.xaml in UWP Applications

Tags: xaml, custom-controls, uwp

This is my Generic.xaml where I define default background color for my control (CustomControlBackground):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TomShane.Framework.Controls">

  <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomControlBackground" Color="Gray"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

  <Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CustomControlBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl">
          <Border
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In App.xaml I want to override the default background from Generic.xaml:

```
<Application
    x:Class="TomShane.Framework.Demo.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TomShane.Framework.Demo"
    xmlns:ctrl="using:TomShane.Framework.Controls"
    RequestedTheme="Dark">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomControlBackground" Color="Red"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

With this technique I am able to override UWP system resources (like SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush), but when I try to override the CustomControlBackground, the control's background stays always gray.

What is the thing I am missing?

Comment: Which one do you load first? Why override the color in App.xaml, why not just define it there in the first place?

Comment: The Generic.xaml is part of a theme/controls assembly separated from the main application. It should be universal and the main application should be able to override some basic colors like accent etc.

I'm not loading Generic.xaml explicitly, it is loaded automatically, so only thing I should need to do is re-define the resource in App.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong.

We can only override upper scope ResourceDictionary in lower scope ResourceDictionary. Actually, it's about the resource lookup behavior but not about which xaml file is loaded first

In WinRT xaml app, the Resource Dictionary scope looks like the following(not MS official picture):
[image]

Based on above, we can override system default resource in app.xaml, we can override system/application resource in page.xaml, and etc.

So in your code, actually, the resource defined in generic.xaml will override the resource you defined in app.xaml. If we simply remove the resource `CustomControlBackground` from the generic.xaml, you will get the red background.

[**update**]

If you do want to have a default theme, you can keep the design, but we cannot use the x:Default for the resourcedictionary.

For example, if the requestedtheme is Dark(in your case). You can simply use the following to override the default one in app.xaml.

```
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomControlBackground" Color="Yellow"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Or you can only put the theme into a separate file and reference it only in the client app's app.xaml. But you have to rewrite the file to use different values.

Comment: That's right, but I need to define default background for CustomControlBackground somewhere in the theme assembly, before overriding it in App.xaml. And because Generic.xaml is loaded automatically I have no control what and when I want to load and in what order.

I'm (almost) sure in old WPF applications the steps in my OP actually work.

Comment: I don't think WPF application will do what you want. Actually, it's related to the resource lookup behavior. The generic.xaml in theme folder will be always the first place to lookup for this scenario. Once the resource is found, the lookup will stop.

Comment: I definitely can be wrong with the WPF, I admit. Anyway, is there a way how to accomplish this in a UWP application? To have a separated assembly with custom controls, that use specific resources and be able to override them in the client app (App.xaml)? If not in XAML then in code behind?

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately it still doesn't work. I have changed all "Default" dictionaries to "Dark" but the color is still not overridden and stays gray. If it works for you, it would be great if I could see your sample code.

Comment: I am so glad this is not true in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Its unfortunate that there isn't a good way to define theme resources for custom controls in such a way that they can be overridden in the same way that the built-in resources, like SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush, can be. But there is a workaround if you're willing to move things around at runtime. The trick is to end up with a situation where your default resources are not contained in Generic.xaml, but are instead defined in a resource dictionary that is merged with the application's resources, where they CAN be overridden. There's more than one way to accomplish this.

One approach would be to create a separate resource dictionary that has an x:Class with an associated code file. Define your default theme resources in it. Then figure out a way to merge an instance of the class into the application's resources at runtime. One way would be in the static constructor of your control. Be careful not to merge more than one instance.

A somewhat different approach, which I like better, is to use code-behind of the resource dictionary in which you define the control's default style. But you can't have code-behind for Generic.xaml, because the framework will never instantiate an instance of the class. Instead, move the style into its own resource dictionary (with x:Class and code-behind) and add an instance of the new dictionary to the merged dictionaries of Generic.xaml. You will be able to move things around in the constructor of this resource dictionary, after the call to InitializeComponent. For example, if in the xaml file you define a resource dictionary in the MergedDictionaries collection and place your theme resources in in it, then at runtime you would be able to remove that dictionary from the MergedDictionaries collection and merge it into the application's resources.

A limitation of either approach is if you want to override resources by theme, i.e. Light and Dark. Placing an overriding resource directly into the resources of App.xaml will work, but will not allow different values for different themes. To achieve this, it is necessary to define the overriding resources inside the ThemeResources of a resource dictionary which itself is placed in the application resource's MergedDictionaries. (I don't know but it kind of seems like this might be a bug.)

CustomControl.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="CustomControlLibrary.Themes.CustomControlTheme" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomControlLibrary">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomControlBackground" Color="#000000" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomControlBackground" Color="#FFFFFF" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CustomControlBackground}" />
    </Style>    

</ResourceDictionary>
```

CustomControl.xaml.cs:

```
namespace CustomControlLibrary.Themes
{
    partial class CustomControlTheme
    {
        public CustomControlTheme()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if(MergedDictionaries.Count > 0)
            {
                var themeResources = MergedDictionaries[0];
                MergedDictionaries.RemoveAt(0);
                Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, themeResources);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:themes="using:CustomControlLibrary.Themes">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <themes:CustomControlTheme />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```